# Reconstructing sub floor after long term leak

Tags: structural, subfloor

My 1930s house is built on a slope and in a room on the ground floor over the lower part of ground that used to be the kitchen I e found an old slow leak when converting to a utility room.

The leaks had rotted out the plywood under the tiled floor, and then also the joists and a wall plate, so I now have a section of wall sitting on nothing. No obvious cracks so far luckily. This is under a window so presumably the load is well spread above.

It looks like there used to be a wooden wall plate sitting on top of wooden joists, and I could put it back how it was but am wondering if there's a better way.

I'm also wondering what to put back on top as the new sub floor. Under the house is ventilated so the air can get a bit damp, I'm dubious about the large chipboard sheets you now get, even the damp resistant ones don't seem great.

It used to have pine floor boards, but I'm assuming there should now be some insulation, perhaps the thick rigid foam type?

I've attached a picture of the rotten end and the floor space.

Any general advice on how to proceed is very welcome.
[image: floor space][image: rotted wall plate]

Comment: Todays studs and joists will be smaller than 1930s.  At least by a 1/4 inch, maybe more.  Will probably need shims to level the new ones to the old ones or the floor will have dips/drops in level.

Comment: Plywood for the subfloor — the thicker the better. And if the plate under the window is really limited to just the window’s width, nothing much is bearing on it. If the rotten section is under the studs beside the window, it’ll need more careful surgery to fix.

Comment: If those are, for example, 2x8" joists, they're most likely actually 8" tall, while modern 2x8's will only be 7.5" tall. You could shim, or you could buy 2x10's (9.5" tall) and rip them down to an actual 8" tall in order to match up the height. It's a bit more expensive on lumber side and time consuming to buy bigger and rip, but it may be easier in the long run, plus it gives you a bit more strength for the entire joist. NOTE: Adjust all lumber sizes to match actual, these numbers were just an example I picked.